# How can i change an image with a if statement in a foreach loop PHP?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach

I'm using CMS ProscessWire.

I've a working foreach loop that shows child's title and 5 links. The links are shown as images. This works flawless. But then I want for an empty link a black and white image to show there's no link. So i made a if statement. But when i put the if statement inside the loop the only child that is shown is the one with an empty link.

Does anyone know how tot resolve this? I think it's a simple thing, but can't figure it out.

PHP-Code:

```
    $rdio='rdio.png';
    $itunes='itunes.png';
    $xbox='xbox.png';
    $googleplay='googleplay.png';
    $spotify='spotify.png';
    $deezer='deezer.png';

    foreach($page->children as $child)

    if(!$child->Rdio) {
$rdio='rdiog.png';
     }
    else
     {
    $rdio='rdio.png';
     }

       echo "<ul style='background-color:#CCC;'>"."<li><h1>{$child->title}</h1></li>".<li><a class='rdio' href='{$child->Rdio}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$rdio' alt='rdio'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='itunes' href='{$child->iTunes}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$itunes' alt='itunes'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='xbox' href='{$child->Xbox}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$xbox' alt='xbox'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='googleplay' href='{$child->GooglePlay}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$googleplay' alt='googleplay'/></li>"."<li><a class='spotify' href='{$child->Spotify}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$spotify' alt='spotify'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='deezer' href='{$child->Deezer}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$deezer' alt='deezer'/></a></li>"."</ul><br/>";
```

Comment: Please explain with more details and add some more code so that we can understand how to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some brackets around `foreach` which only executes the following IF statement and continues to print out a single element on your page. To correct this, just add brackets around the foreach loop like this:

```
    $rdio='rdio.png';
    $itunes='itunes.png';
    $xbox='xbox.png';
    $googleplay='googleplay.png';
    $spotify='spotify.png';
    $deezer='deezer.png';

    foreach($page->children as $child) {

    if(!$child->Rdio) {
$rdio='rdiog.png';
     }
    else
     {
    $rdio='rdio.png';
     }

       echo "<ul style='background-color:#CCC;'>"."<li><h1>{$child->title}</h1></li>".<li><a class='rdio' href='{$child->Rdio}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$rdio' alt='rdio'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='itunes' href='{$child->iTunes}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$itunes' alt='itunes'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='xbox' href='{$child->Xbox}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$xbox' alt='xbox'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='googleplay' href='{$child->GooglePlay}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$googleplay' alt='googleplay'/></li>"."<li><a class='spotify' href='{$child->Spotify}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$spotify' alt='spotify'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='deezer' href='{$child->Deezer}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$deezer' alt='deezer'/></a></li>"."</ul><br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! didn't noticed haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `empty` method:

```
$rdio='rdio.png';
$itunes='itunes.png';
$xbox='xbox.png';
$googleplay='googleplay.png';
$spotify='spotify.png';
$deezer='deezer.png';

foreach($page->children as $child) {

if(empty($child->Rdio)) {
$rdio='rdiog.png';
 }
else
 {
$rdio='rdio.png';
 }

   echo "<ul style='background-color:#CCC;'>"."<li><h1>{$child->title}</h1></li>".<li><a class='rdio' href='{$child->Rdio}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$rdio' alt='rdio'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='itunes' href='{$child->iTunes}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$itunes' alt='itunes'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='xbox' href='{$child->Xbox}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$xbox' alt='xbox'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='googleplay' href='{$child->GooglePlay}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$googleplay' alt='googleplay'/></li>"."<li><a class='spotify' href='{$child->Spotify}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$spotify' alt='spotify'/></a></li>"."<li><a class='deezer' href='{$child->Deezer}'><img src='../site/templates/img/$deezer' alt='deezer'/></a></li>"."</ul><br/>";
```